# How to use js to display the block I've put "none" on in css?

Tags: javascript, css, button, popup

So I have a button before a wrapper div I've made. My problem is to make it possible to click the `<button>` and make my `<div>` (I have put it on display:none) + my body `background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` to reappear and show the button slightly through that greyish hue.

How do I do it with JavaScript?

```
<body>
    <button>Click me!</button>
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: could you please post your markup? Otherwise it's quite difficult to help you.

Comment: ´<body>
<button>Click me!</button>

<div id="wrapper"></div>

</body>´

Comment: sorry new at this site, so i don't know how to make it look as proper as a few comments I've seen here :/